# Show all tags for a views query?

Tags: views

I am trying to write a views_query_alter hook and I want to identify the query I'm interested in. I have found [the method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/interface/QueryAlterableInterface/7)s `hasTag()`, `hasAllTags()`, and `hasAnyTag()`, but I don't already know which tags I'm looking for. How can I get Drupal to tell me what tags already exist on queries? I didn't see any `getTags()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you mean [hook_query_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7) here by mentioning `hasTag()`, `hasAllTags()`, and `hasAnyTag()` not [hook_views_query_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7).

You can understand more about these methods from this [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/310077).

By help of these methods you can specify the targeted query, when you apply this in your module. A example code has been given in answer at [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787130/how-to-alter-a-query-and-join-with-another-table-in-views-3-0-drupal-7-x), which helped me long ago to modify a query of views.

```
function MY_MODULE_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if ($query->hasAllTags('views', '[MY VIEW NAME]')) {
    $query->addJoin('INNER', 'taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'node.nid = ti.nid');
    $query->condition('ti.tid', '2,3', 'IN');
  }
}
```

If you are looking for the tags which you can use, just try to print `$query` inside the `hook` & see the result on the page where you are working. You will get what query you can target & the tags which you can use.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: So there's no way to get the query object to say what tags it has on it? I have to know what tag I'm looking for in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by tags here ?

Comment: What I mean is the string you are searching for when you call `hasTag()` on it. Instead of asking the query object if it has tag 'X', I want to call something like `getTags()` and have it return to me an array of 'X', 'Y', and 'Z'. I want it to tell me what tags it has instead of me asking it.

Comment: Just try to DPM $query variable & see the result on the page where you are working. You will get what query you can target & the tags which you can use..

Comment: @user1359 No need of separate answer, I just edited the same answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `hook_views_query_alter` takes the view object and its query as arguments, so to identify the query I want to modify, I actually will look at the view object to see if it's the one I want.

Comment: hook_views_query_alter and hook_query_alter are different.  Notably you can't nest condition groups in hook_views_query_alter

Answer (score 0):

The right way to get all tags from a query is:

```
dpm($query->alterTags);
```